# android pre-fill sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database in my application. My application shouldn't ship this as an empty database but certain records need to be created before the user can use the application the first time. Of course I can have many insert statements, but that seems to be very strange. I thought of something like http://vineetyadav.com/tutorials/11-adding-prefilled-sqlite-database-to-android-app.html which basically works, but that means that my manually created DB needs all internal tables like android_metadata as well. So I either need to know what internal tables exist and how to fill them. Or another smart way of having a pre-filled database. Any suggestions?

Thanks, A.

Comment: Why don't you use SQLiteOpenHelper to get your database connection, and override it's `onCreate` method to fill in data from a resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read in a flat file from the SD card with 1 insert statement per line and iterate through that file.

Here's a similar example in which I read a file and add a ContactItem to my contact_list:

```
public ArrayList<ContactItem> readInputFile(Context context, String filename) {
    String text = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<ContactItem> contact_list = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();
    contact_list.clear();  // Clear any existing contacts when a new file is read
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        // Repeat until EOF
        while (((text = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
            if (!(text.length() > 1024)) {  //  If we read more than 1k per line there's a problem with the input file format
                ContactItem c = new ContactItem(text);
                if (c.getIsValid()) {
                    //  We were able to parse a well formed phone number from the last line read
                    contact_list.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_fileNotFound, 1).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_ioException, 1).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { // EOFException (or other, but EOF is handled and most likely)
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_generalFailure, 1).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return contact_list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I stored the data in the res/raw directory as JSON. When the application was opened for the first time, I used an AsyncTask, read the JSON file (used the GSON library) and filled my database with it.

I have tried this with around 1000 records and it worked for me. It still took some time - around 15-30 seconds on an emulator.

Not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I just did the insert statements, but I only had 2 so it didn't seem over the top for me.

If you need to know the internal tables why don't you just extract the database from your application and give it a look with any SQLite database explorer (I use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/))?

android_metadata is shown in the SQLite Database Browser as being created by `CREATE TABLE android_metadata(locale TEXT)` for example.

Possibly insert a statement to make sure that's how it would look.

Then you can easily recreate it and add it?

Comment: yes and no, take android_metadata, in my case there is only my locale in it. Then I need to figure out how to set it for these users. I guess it would be possilbe. But it all is some kind of guessing which might fail on devices I cannot test. As a last resort okay, but adhere to a spec I would prefer...

Comment: add question: if you have far more than 2 entries, would you store the inital values in an array and put into the db or into a flat file or into a xml file?

Comment: Ahh... I did not know that - sorry. As to the 2nd question - phew, I wish I knew what would be the most efficient way of doing so, but I don't. I'm still a novice - my DB was just a simple IP list so an easy implementation. :) My gut says xml or flat file (possibly slower than xml?) is good practice, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: I would guess flat file is fast since you don't have to parse a xml file... but I am a novice too, maybe someone else knows...